# How can i avoid a short page shift using fancybox 3

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using fancybox (version 3.5.7) for some image galleries on a joomla-website. It works great untill a small shift of the entire body of the thumbnail-page on opening the page, on opening the fancybox-modal and on closing it. The page is shifting  for a very short time and comes afterwards back to its original position (see effect on http://www.fischer-club.ch/index.php/unser-verein/retro-fotos/1966-training-am-sonntag).
How can I avoid this shift?

I am using fancybox in combination with another jQuery script called masonry. I tried to deactivate the masonry script, but the shift still occurs. I've also tried different solutions from other posts to shift-problems with fancybox, but they are mostly regarding the version 2 of fancybox, so that nothing helped.
The shift occurs on different browsers but not on smartphones.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script hides page scrollbars by default by applying `overflow: hidden;` for `body` element. Since that causes body element to expand to fill free space, the script also calculates width of the vertical scroll bar and uses that value to set right margin for `body` element. That works very well (as you can see on homepage and all demos), but this can be disrupted by adding some additional CSS rules, for example, by setting 100% width for body element.

The solution would be to remove (usually unnecessary) CSS rules that breaks default workflow or by setting `$.fancybox.defaults.hideScrollbar = false;` to prevent hiding page scrollbars.

Edit: In your case, the page shift is caused by this CSS rule:

```
body {
    transition: all 400ms ease;
}
```

E.g., you are animating everything, even `margin-right` added by the fancybox. So, either remove that CSS rule that or change `all` to `width` or whatever you wish to animate.

Comment: Thanks for this very clear answer! The CSS rule comes fom my joomla-template. Therefore I've added following css in the head section of my page: body {transition: none;}. It resolves the shift on opening and closing the fancybox-modal. However, a shift still occurs by opening the page. Any idea from which CSS rule is it caused?

Comment: Well, it does not seem to be CSS related problem. I suspect that this 
 - "$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() { $grid.masonry('layout'); });" - could be the cause of layout change, but I can not be sure without access to source code :)

Comment: i've been using the imageloaded script to prevent an issue withe the masonry script (unloaded images can throw off Masonry layouts and cause item elements to overlap). See unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4.1.4/imagesloaded.pkgd.js . However the shift effect still occurs als after deleting this script... Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think the problem has nothing to do with fancybox. It's due to the joomla template. Since i am loading the images with a php script, the page doesn't know by loading if it needs a scrollbar or not. After a few milisecond it notices that a scrollbar is needed, so the page is shifting left by the width of the scrollbar.